# why does rails generate scaffold fail? message is add pg to gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
fails with message Gem::LoadError

The error message indicates that the gemfile does not have gem pg but it   does.  Also it says to ensure that the version of pg is at minimum required   by ActiveRecord.  I am not sure what the minimum version of pg would be.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a new app from the start.  With the database=postgresql option.

rails new app --database=postgresql

and answered Yes for all the new things it created.  This set up my gemfile corectly.  And now rails generate scaffold is a success .